# (SQL) DataTables server-side column sorting with dynamic columns

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, datatables

I believe this question is mostly related to SQL, but I will give context for what we are trying to do in case someone has done it before.

We are trying to implement [DataTables JQuery plug-in](https://datatables.net/) with [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) using SQL Server for our ASP .NET Core MVC app. On top of that, we have dynamic columns, which we were able to generate for DataTables using [this github code](https://github.com/martinberlin/datatables-dynamic-columns/blob/master/dynamic-headers.html).

We have been successful in handling paging, entry #, and column searching processes (couldn't figure out global search, and we got column search to work only with SQL views). However, sorting columns are only handled partially.

The issue with column sorting is that we don't know how many and what type of columns could be returned. This means that there may be an NVARCHAR column containing strings that are currency ($3,403.09), or NVARCHARs that are regular numbers, and some of the values in those columns may be NULL. Same with dates with varying formats. We don't know how to handle sorting these NVARCHARs in SQL as the correct type instead of a string. Having said that, client-side DataTables is able to deal with identifying how data should be sorted.

I don't expect an answer, but if anyone has handled a similar situation, I'd greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some of them have numeric collations.)

Comment: SQL Server. Sorry, I forgot to tag it.